# Как создать анимацию при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: android, android-animation

Как создать анимацию при нажатии на кнопку? И есть ли готовые свойства в xml для элемента View, что б это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true">
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_checked"
        android:state_checked="true">
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/button">
    </item>
</selector>
```

Смотря какая именно анимация вам нужна. Из наиболее простых вариантов:

1. Для любого View, в том числе и ViewGroup, можно установить атрибут `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`, что при наличии onClickListener будет создавать "круги на воде" при клике
2. Использовать в бэкграунде селектор. Это не совсем анимация, бэкграунд просто подменяется мгновенно при смене состояния кнопки, но при адекватном подборе оформления это достаточно неплохо смотрится(чет у меня ерунда с редактором, поэтому пример сверху... снизу он не отображается. Поправьте кто может)